# Google Tag Manager Trigger equals multiple classes

Tags: google-tag-manager

I have a lookup table set up for a variable.

What's working is when I do a trigger for something like:

`Variable Name` equals `Lookup Table Value 1`

But what I need is something like:

`Variable Name` equals `Lookup Table Value 1` or `Lookup Table Value 2`

I tried what amounts to:

`Variable Name` equals `Lookup Table Value 1, Lookup Table Value 2` but that didn't work.

Is there basically a way to do an "or" for triggers using variables like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using `Variable Name` **equals** `Lookup Table Value 1` or `Lookup Table Value 2` 

you should use `Variable Name` **matches regEx(ignore case)** `Lookup Table Value 1 | Lookup Table Value 2`

Notice the `|`

Comment: Thanks! Important note that you can't have spaces around the `|`. So it needs to be `Lookup Table Value 1|Lookup Table Value 2`

Comment: Or instead of a lookup table you could move the logic to a regex table, although without knowing your specific use cases it is hard to say if this would make things easiert.

Comment: Yes thats true @jonmrich. i added space so it would be easy to spot it :)

Answer (score 3):

For two class A B

Then varibles Click Element => Matches css selector => .A,.B comma separated

[image]